# Return all attributes of an HtmlElement in Web browser

Tags: c#, html, xml, xmlwriter, stringwriter

I need to get all of the attributes from my webbrowser.currently,I am using GetAttribute() but this way,I need to know the name of the attributes.
Imagine I do not know what is in my webbrowser.
My C# code:

```
        StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();            
        XmlWriter xWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strWriter, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true });
        xWriter.WriteStartElement("Items");
        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA"))
        {
            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Item");
            xWriter.WriteElementString("GUID", el.Id);
            xWriter.WriteElementString("Type", el.GetAttribute("type").ToUpper());
            xWriter.WriteElementString("Name", el.Name);
            xWriter.WriteElementString("Value", el.GetAttribute("value"));
            xWriter.WriteElementString("MaxLength", el.GetAttribute("maxlength"));
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

I have searched a lot but I did not find any thing useful.

Comment: I also tried using Html Agility Pack(http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples) but it was not such a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I guess this could be a solution or the first step. First, you have to reference to `microsoft.mshtml`

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA"))
{

    HTMLTextAreaElement textarea = (HTMLTextAreaElement)el.DomElement;

    xWriter.WriteStartElement("Item");
    xWriter.WriteElementString("GUID", el.Id);

    foreach (var attribute in textarea.attributes)
    {
         String name = attribute.name;
         String value = attribute.value;

         xWriter.WriteElementString(name, value);
    }

    xWriter.WriteEndElement();
}
```