# Getting complete input tag string in webbrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm having to use the webbrowser control in a small application to not fill in field values but the opposite extract them, what i am trying to do is grab the complete input string for example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
```

I know by using:

```
        foreach (HtmlElement element in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            Helpers.ReturnMessage(element.GetAttribute("name"));
        }
```

We can get the value of the `name="username"` part by using the code above, but is there a way to get the entire string which in this case would be:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" size="40" required="required"/>
```

Ideally what i am looking to do is grab this part from each `input` -> `name="username"` it could be `id="value"` in some examples so i couldn't hard code it, or would i need to use regex of some kind? thank you for any help.

Comment: I guess you can use `.ToString()` on `webBrowser.Document.` to get raw html and then parse it with regular expression. 
BTW i think better to use Selenium, because it provides more options in API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [HtmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement?view=netframework-4.8#properties) doesn't provide any capabilities to enumerate attributes(at least in a [generic enough way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632517/3745022)) so the simplest solution will be to use its OuterHtml property and parse it with https://html-agility-pack.net/

```
var inputHtml = _webBrowser
    .Document
    .GetElementsByTagName("input")
    .Cast<HtmlElement>()
    .Single()
    .OuterHtml;     
var elementHtmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
elementHtmlDoc.LoadHtml(inputHtml);
var attributesDictionary = elementHtmlDoc
    .DocumentNode
    .ChildNodes
    .Single()
    .Attributes
    .ToDictionary(
        attr => attr.Name, 
        attr => attr.Value);
MessageBox.Show(
    String.Join(Environment.NewLine, attributesDictionary),
    "Attributes");
```

If your really need to get attributes HTML string for that element, then it can be (not ideal but still [mostly reliable in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)) done with a bit of regular expressions over the OuterHtml of the element

```
var attributesString = Regex
    .Match(inputHtml, @"^<\s*\S+\s+(?<attributes>[^\>]*)>") // WebBrowser removes closing slash, so we do not need to handle it.
    .Groups["attributes"]
    .ToString();
```

Though it won't be the **actual** HTML used(as WebBrowser seems to rearrange original attributes and provides a slightly modified HTML). So if you want to get the actual HTML, then you will have to obtain the original .html file(obviously won't work with SPA and Ajax-heavy sites) separately and parse it with HtmlAgilityPack.